# How to send JSP as response to AJAX call

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, spring-mvc

I want to send a JSP page which consists of some divs and table as part of AJAX response from spring framework, is there any way to send JSP as a response of AJAX call

Comment: I guess that by JSP you actually mean the HTML generated by a JSP.

Answer (score 3):

Sending JSP by AJAX makes no sense, it is basically the HTML generated by a JSP that is sent over to the browser through AJAX, as rightly pointed out by the lost.

You do not need any server-side coding for this. All you need is to write some JavaScript on client-side to receive your HTML asynchronously. For this, I would recommend using some JavaScript framework like jQuery, otherwise, it would make your life hell.

Assuming that the page you want to access by AJAX has the link **http://domain:port/mypage.htm**. First you need to include jQuery in your base JSP (JSP in which former page has to load by AJAX):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Then you need to call jQuery's AJAX function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "http://domain:port/mypage.htm",
        success: function(data) {
            // Now you have your HTML in "data", do whatever you want with it here in this function         
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: also consider using $.load() instead if you are trying to replace a portion of code with AJAX, works very nicely in conjunction with JSP, you can even fill your Model and use that model in the AJAX JSP.  I actually have a folder within my JSP folder named AJAX, to show that those JSP's should not be rendered by themselves, but rather as part of other pages

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's no magic to this though. In your Java AJAX handler just return a forward or redirect to the JSP page you want. The response will then be available as the `responseText` in your AJAX callback.

You can use JSP to generate just the elements you need as a sort of incomplete HTML fragment then returns this from your server-side handler. Then in your JavaScript callback you can insert the fragment into your existing HTML like this

```
element.innerHTML = resp.responseText 
//element is the parent you want to insert to 
//resp is the parameter supplied to your callback
```